# Sorting objects by y value before rendering?

Tags: c++, graphics

I have a 2D top-down 45 degree game like pokemon or Zelda. Since the y value of an object determines it's depth, objects need to be drawn in order of their y value. So when your standing behind a tree for example, the tree is drawn on top of your player to look like you are standing behind the tree.

My current design would be to draw a row of tiles, and then draw any players standing on that row, then draw the next row, and then draw any players standing on that. This way any tile that has a higher y value than the player is drawn in front of them to simulate depth.

However, my players are currently a `std::vector` of objects that is simply iterated and drawn after all the tiles are drawn. For my method to work, I would have to either iterate the vector for **every row** of tiles, and only render if they are on the current row, OR sort every player by y value somehow each frame. Both these methods seem quite CPU intensive, and maybe I am over thinking it and there is a simpler way of simulating depth in this type of game.

*Edit:*
This game is an MMORPG type game, so there could potentially be many players/NPC's walking around which is why I need a very efficient method.

And ideas or comments would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Disgregard my original suggestion, if you read it; it was daft.)

As far as I can tell, you basically have to iterate over a sorted container each time you render a frame; there will be a computational penalty for this, and having to do a copy and sort each time will not be that bad (O(N log N) sorting time, I'd guess).

A clever data structure might help you here; an array containing a vector of game objects as each element, for example. Each element of the array represents a row of your tiled grid, and you iterate over your vector of objects and bin them into your depth buffer array (which will take approximately O(N) time). Then just iterate over the vector representing each row and draw each object in turn, again O(N).

There are probably cleverer z-buffering techniques, but I'll leave those as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::set` or `std::map` instead of `vector` to keep your objects in sorted order. Unfortunately you wouldn't be able to simply modify their position, you would have to remove/insert each time you needed to change the `y` coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you aren't also attempting to sort your players according to other criteria then you can get away with just sorting your players by y-coordinate every time you want to iterate through them.  As long as you use a sort that runs in linear time when the input is mostly sorted then you will probably not even incur O(n log n) time for this step.  I'm making the assumption here that your set of players changes slowly and that their y-coordinates will also change slowly.  If this is the case then every time you need to sort the vector it will already be mostly-sorted, and something like Smooth sort or Tim sort will run in linear time.

For c++ it looks like you can find an implementation of Tim sort [here](https://github.com/swenson/sort).

Answer (score 0):

If you have space, another option would be to create an array of lists of players, with the index of the array being the row number, and the array containing a collection of the players in that row.

As I mentioned, this will require a bit of extra memory, and some bookeeping every time a player moves to a different row, but then drawing is simply a matter of iterating through the rows, and drawing the players that are present in that row.